# Python: Global name is not defined (but it is not a global variable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

Sorry for asking another question after I recently asked one. I have tried everything under the sun trying to fix this problem, and I can't fix it. If you ask me what I have tried my answer would be "I don't know", because my head is spinning after all the work I have done trying to fix this error.

```
def function1( ):
    if driver == "Steve Park" and season == "2000"
        averageFinish = 10.0
    return averageFinish 

def function2( ):
    momentum = int ( input ( "Enter the momentum for the driver: " ) )
    global driver, season
    if driver == "Steve Park" and season == "2000" and momentum == "5"
        newAverageFinish == function1( ) - 2.0
    print( newAverageFinish )
    return newAverageFinish

def main( ):
    global driver
    driver = input ( "Enter a driver: " )
    global season
    season = int ( input ( "Enter a season: " ) )
    function1( )
    function2( )
    # Output should be 8.0
```

The output is:

```
Enter a driver: Steve Park
Enter a season: 2000
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line6, in main
File "<stdin>", line5, in function1
Name Error: global name 'averageFinish' is not defined
```

I have no idea why it thinks average finish is a global. Also, the keyboard I use on my laptop isn't working so I typed in the code on my tablet. I am using the android app QPython3. I don't know if it produces different error messages compared to computer python interpreters. The reason why I am not waiting until I get my keyboard is because I am REALLY anxious to get the algorithm finish for my personal program. I'm testing out my planned algorithm in QPython3 until my keyboard comes.

Comment: You are missing semicolons on your `if` statements. That code shouldn't run at all.

Comment: Use the return values as arguments for your other functions, saves you messing around with globals and is much cleaner and easier to follow.

Comment: This code isn't quite what you ran... it has syntax errors and `function1` doesn't have 5 lines. I notice that not all of your code paths set values (suppose `if driver == "Steve Park" and season == "2000"`) is False, then you never set the variable but try to return it anyway. But that would result in an `UnboundLocalError`. I suspect that the real code as a `global` statement in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try running below code, I have fixed the issues you had in your code,

```
def function1( ):
    if driver == "Steve Park" and season == 2000:
        averageFinish = 10.0
    return averageFinish 

def function2( ):
    momentum = int ( input ( "Enter the momentum for the driver: " ) )
    #momentum = 5
    global driver, season
    if driver == "Steve Park" and season == 2000 and momentum == 5:
        newAverageFinish = function1( ) - 2.0
    print( newAverageFinish )
    return newAverageFinish

def main( ):
    global driver
    driver = input ( "Enter a driver: " )
    #driver = "Steve Park"

    global season
    season = int ( input ( "Enter a season: " ) )
    #season = 2000

    function1( )
    function2( )
    # Output should be 8.0

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the error message indicates that the interpreter is attempting to find a global variable named `averageFinish` when it executes line 5, and that no such variable exists.  You are right that `averageFinish` isn't a global variable.  But the interpreter is right that it's not defined for the case where the "if" statement in `function1` evaluates to false.  The reason why it's false is that you convert `season` to an `int` as soon as the user enters it, but in the if statement you compare `season` to a string.  You wrote `season == "2000"` instead of `season == 2000` which is probably what you intended.

As a matter of good practice you should write functions that take arguments instead of trying to pass information around by means of global variables.  But that is not why this program is failing.

Comment: I don't like using globals unless they are constants. Are you also against global constants? Thanks for explaining it to me. Also, I did have the semicolons, I forgot to add them to the post. Your explanation makes sense. I thought all user input had to have " " I didn't know that was converting it to a string.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is correct.  I believe you mean colon, not semicolon.  Global constants are fine.  User input is indeed a string, but you converted it to int before assigning it to the variable `season`, so in subsequent logic that name refers to an int.  In Python, and in every other language I know of, "2000" is a string and 2000 is an int.  Python is a little unusual in that the expression `2000 == "2000"` is acceptable and evaluates false; in many languages it would be a compiler or run-time error.